# VsVim: How to enable jumps?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, vsvim

In vim I can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> to jump to the last edited location. This works perfectly fine in pure vim. However this does not work in VsVim. Is there a way to enable this feature in VsVim for Visual Studio?

Comment: https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/Supported-Features

Comment: hmm, too bad, not supported :-(. Thanks for the (obvious) link.